# Format cells if Date within last 30 days?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

Currently hardcoding the date to apply conditional formatting. Is there a way to do this based on a variable range of the last 30 days?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first menu select 'Date is' and from the second select 'in the last month'

However that will not highlight future dates and may not be what you want

In that case replace '2018-02-27' with `=now()-30`